# What is wrong with this Exception Handling in Java

Tags: java, android, exception

Below is the full method. It returns the HTML Code of the given URL as a String.
After certain tests I came to the conclusion that the try block is skipped. But I don't know why.

```
    public static String getHtml(String url)
 {
     StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
     try {
         HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
         HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
         HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);


         BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
             new InputStreamReader(
               response.getEntity().getContent()
             )
           );

         String line = null;
         char c = '"'; //The Java complains about this type of char So I removed it from the source.
         while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
           for(int i = line.length()-1; i >0; --i){
               if (line.charAt(i) != c){
                   result.append(line);
               }
           }
         }
         return result.toString();
     } catch(Exception e){
            result.append("<p><img src=http://desperateshadows.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/img_0721.jpg?w=730 class=size-full alt=Green green not evergreen /></p><p>Little flower at a glance</p>"); //A test Source

         return result.toString();
     }



 }
```

Comment: First: don't "eat" the exception. Call `e.printStacktrace();` before returning the result. Second: post the stacktrace from the logcat. Also do you have the Internet permission added in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

Comment: what your log cat shows.????

Comment: how do you know it's skipped?

Comment: Yeah I have Inernet Permission.

Comment: What's wrong is that you haven't put enough debugging output in your catch block. `Log.e(TAG, "getHtml() caught an exception", e);` to preserve your sanity.

Comment: I tried the Toast at each block to know which block runs and which doesn't.

Comment: What is the exception you are getting?

Comment: "After certain tests I came to the conclusion that the try block is skipped." 1. You are mistaken. 2. After *what* tests? 3. Any exception handling that doesn't include logging or printing the actual exception is fatally flawed, and reduces debugging (and forum assistance) to a guessing game.

Comment: Toast (requires UI thread) and networking (forbidden on UI thread by default) do not mix well.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling execute() from.the UI thread. Blocking operations are not allowed to be run on the UI Thread since Android 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

put permission for Internet access in android manifest.xml

```
<manifest xlmns:android...> ...
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" >...
    </application>    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```